# Allow user to select only todays date or future date using Angularjs ui bootstrap

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I am using ui bootstrap directive ui-datepicker. I want set the datepicker that the user can only select today's date or future date. here is the html of datepicker:

```
 <div class="input-group">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control"
                                       uib-datepicker-popup="yyyy-MM-dd"
                                       name="start_date"
                                       ng-model="loan.start_date"
                                       is-open="popup1.opened"
                                       datepicker-options="dateOptions"
                                       ng-required="true"
                                       close-text="Close"
                                       alt-input-formats="altInputFormats"
                                 />
                          <span class="input-group-btn">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open1()"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></button>
```

Here is what I have on the javascript side:

```
  $scope.inlineOptions = {
    customClass: getDayClass,
    minDate: new Date(),
    showWeeks: true
};

$scope.dateOptions = {
    dateDisabled: disabled,
    formatYear: 'yy',
   maxDate: new Date("2020-04-1"),
    minDate: new Date() ,
    startingDay: 1
};
```

How can I go about doing accomplishing this, thanks in advance.

Comment: What's `disabled`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your javascript looks ok, but your mark-up appears to be a bit off.  Take a look at this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/9whZ9XUc14ICyzSYgw9p?p=preview) (modified from Angular original), it is a working example.

```
 $scope.dateOptions = {
    dateDisabled: disabled,
    formatYear: 'yy',
    minDate: new Date(),
    startingDay: 1
  };


  <p class="input-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" uib-datepicker-popup ng-model="dt" is-open="popup2.opened" datepicker-options="dateOptions" ng-required="true" close-text="Close" />
          <span class="input-group-btn">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open2()"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></button>
          </span>
        </p>
```